# Finding All Data Between Two Datetime Points

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, matplotlib

I'm trying to make an iPython notebook that graphs all data between two datetime points. I have most of the work done already, I just need to make it so I can select a start date and and end date. The program's job is to store all of that data into a variable.

Here's a snippet of data (keep in mind, I have 240,000 points of data)

```
[datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 17, 40, 55), datetime.datetime(2014,
6, 27, 17, 40, 56), datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 17, 40, 57),
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 17, 40, 58), datetime.datetime(2014, 6,
27, 17, 40, 59), datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 17, 41),
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 17, 41, 1), datetime.datetime(2014, 6,
27, 17, 41, 2), datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 17, 41, 3),
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 17, 41, 4), datetime.datetime(2014, 6,
27, 17, 41, 5), datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 17, 41, 6),
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 17, 41, 7), datetime.datetime(2014, 6,
27, 17, 41, 8), datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 17, 41, 9),
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 17, 41, 10), datetime.datetime(2014, 6,
27, 17, 41, 11), datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 27, 17, 41, 12)]
```

It's formatted for the most part (Year, month, day, 24-hour, minute, second).

How can I make it something like:

```
startYear = 2014 
startMonth = 6 
startDay = 27 
startHour = 17
startMinute = 40 
startSecond = 55

endYear = 2014 
endMonth = 6 
endDay = 28 
endHour = 17 
endMinute = 40
endSecond = 55
```

I'm using date2num on the block of data and I think that using date2num on the desired dates will leave with just cross searching for the same number. I just need the end result to be like:

```
BetweenTime = (StartTime):(EndTime)
```

So that I can plug BetweenTime into my graph.

Any help is appreciated, I"m relatively new to Python.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by plugging `BetweenTime` into your graph, are you trying to shown them as text values in the plot? Or you are trying to set them as the `xlim`?

Comment: This is my graph: http://prntscr.com/40m59y
I'm plotting close to 1 million points of data. Basically, what I'm doing right now is plugging in my Time data on the x-axis and later it converts it to the date format. That part is already done as you can see in the graph. I just need to make it so I can select a certain time window to view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datetime objects are comparable (See "datetime1 < datetime2 Compares datetime to datetime. (4)" in https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date), so you can do:

```
sDate = datetime(starYear,...,startSecond) #fill this in
eDate = datetime(endYear,...,endSecond) #fill this in
for i in data:
    if i >= sDate and i <= eDate:
         #DO SOMETHING WITH i IT SHOULD BE INCLUDED
```

Comment: Or, you could write: `sDate <= i <= eDate`. [Look here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in).

Comment: Either works. That is more intuitive if someone is from a math background (python is great for this), and mine is more intuitive I think for programmers who may be used to C like if (COND1) && (COND2)...

Comment: Ran into another problem, probably something else in the code. I appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: Wait, I'm having a problem. I'm only getting one value back. Here's a screenshot: http://prntscr.com/40mi7g

Am I doing something wrong? I need all of the data between startDate and endDate to be stored into a single variable.

Comment: You are resetting betweentime to i each time; you need to append it instead. Have something like betweentime += i, or make betweentime a list and do betweentime.append[i]. Not sure of the format you need.